# How to permanently disable chrome's warning when filtering requests on network tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

On [Chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) within the `Network` tab we have the functionality to filter responses, however when the filter is applied a warning pops out within the tab saying `Search headers and response bodies for <your-filter>` followed by a button to display all responses.

[image]

This warning really bothers me because a good space of my screen is basically dead when the filter is applied.

**My question is if is there a way to either permanently disable this warning or to at least close it?**

In case of not having a way to close the warning, does anyone knows a work-around that does not involves the filter to easily remove `OPTIONS` from requests?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome has removed the flag when filtering out Network requests. Thanks Chrome Team